# Serve static files with express from within electron-forge app

Tags: node.js, express, electron, electron-forge

I've written a quick [Electron Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/) app that simply runs an express webserver that serves static files locally.  I prefer this to running a node process directly for usability.

**main.js**

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import express from 'express';

const exApp = express();
exApp.use(express.static('web-app'));
exApp.listen(3333);

let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  // ...
  });

  // ...
};

// ...
```

I use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy the files I need to serve into the `.webpack/main/web-app/` directory.

**webpack.main.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './src/main.js',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web-app'), to: 'web-app' }
    ]),
  ]
};
```

This works perfectly in development (via `yarn start`).

When I try to run `yarn make`, it successfully builds the app and generates a runnable exe, but trying to access `http://localhost:3333/` after running the app, results in a `Cannot GET /` 404 message.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was serving in development was actually the `web-app` directory relative to the node process, and not the one copied into `.webpack/...`.

To serve the proper files in production, I changed the `exApp.use()` line to:

```js
exApp.use(express.static('resources/app/.webpack/main/web-app'));
```